# Can't install NetBeans on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, netbeans

Trying to install NetBeans 12.0 on MacOS. I have JDK 11 installed through SDKman. Several answers on this site alluded to checking if JAVA_HOME variable is set, and entering echo $JAVA_HOME gives the output /Users/demon/.sdkman/candidates/java/current, meaning I do have the JDK installed, however both the CLI and GUI installer show the error :
*The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

installer: Error - NetBeans IDE cannot be installed. This software can be installed with Java 8 or newer. Please download and install the latest update of Java 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and restart NetBeans installation.*

---

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Instead of trusting the message about Java 8 or newer, use Java 8. Java 11 was a major change to the language and broke a lot of software.

Comment: Please open the Terminal an execute "java -version" and "which java" and post the results here.

By the way: IntelliJ works also fine with Java 11.

Comment: @MirkoEbert "java -version" gives openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode) whereas "which java" gives /Users/demon/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java. I used SDKman to install my jdk.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah that worked, I simply installed Java 8 and NetBeans installed normally. /usr/libexec/java_home used to give the output that a JRE was not found, but it worked now. Cheers.

Comment: Please try "javac -version".

Comment: @gamermaimer Java 11 removed the JRE. Java has changed significantly since 2018. Java 16 is the current release.